# Why does Zürich lose the “i” when adding an adjective ending?

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending, inflection, place-name

I have searched around on this site and google and I cannot seem to find an answer for this.

I know that Zürich seems to be a bit of an odd city in the German language due to the  fact that when you need to add an adjective ending, you also need to remove the *i,* e.g.:

> Neue Zürcher Zeitung

What is the etymological reasoning behind this? As far as I know, no other cities do this in German.

Comment: vgl. München - Münchner Abendblatt

Comment: I'm afraid, but you don't need to remove the "i". E.g. the expression "Züricher Flughafen" (airport) can often be found. I think "Zürcher" is only a matter of Schwyzerdütsch, and this newspaper decided to put it in its name.

Comment: @tofro: Aber [Münch**e**ner Kammerorchester](//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchener_Kammerorchester).

Comment: Another example is "Dresdner Straße" or "Dresdener Straße" (derived from "Dresden") which both can be found. Or consider, even a bit more strange, "Eisleber Wiesenmarkt" (derived from "Eisleben", see http://www.wiesenmarkt.de/). I guess this all is just for the ease of pronounciation.

Comment: Ah really? I didn't realise other cities did this too, and yes saying Züricher vs Zürcher, the latter does seem slightly easier to pronounce. Thanks all :)

Comment: *Zürich* isn’t even that special: *Lübsches Marzipan* derives from *Lübeck.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As IQV already said: There is no etymology behind that. I think that the reason for this is the colloquial language. If I talk about Munich *(München)* and people from Munich *(Münchener)* I won’t pronounce every syllable. If I say *Münchener* it sounds like *Münchner*.

Maybe its comparable to *wanna* instead of *want to* in English.

I don’t know the exact reason of the naming of this newspaper — but I found [this little Q and A](http://www.tagblattzuerich.ch/aktuell/warum/warum-detail/article/warum-schreiben-wir-eigentlich-zuercher-und-nicht-zuericher.html). The question is exactly yours and the answer comes from a person who deals with *Schwizerdütsch (Idiotikon).* He says, that *Züricher* and *Zürcher* were equal in literature over centuries and *Zürcher* has something to do with pronounciation.

One more thing: I found a forum [where a person from Zürich explains](http://www.geschichtsforum.de/f73/die-nzz-wird-225-jahre-alt-4289/), that people from this city always call themselves *Zürcher* — and that this little difference is quite important to them (3rd post).

Comment: Please do not use acute accents instead of apostrophes; it looks horrible and the spacing is catastrophic.

Answer (score -1):

There is no etymology behind *Zürcher. Zürcher* is the Swiss German (schwizerdütsche) expression for *Züricher.* In the [German Wikipedia](//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizerdeutsch) you can find a broad explanation of the genesis of Schwizerdütsch as a German dialect.

And there is no need to remove the *i* when using an adjective form. You can find examples where *Züricher* is used, e. g. *Züricher Flughafen.*

As mentioned in the comments above, there are also other German city names, which **can** lose the last vocal like *München* or *Dresden.*

Comment: Wrong. It is not true that *“Zürcher* is the Swiss German (schwizerdütsche) expression for *Züricher.”* It is just as standard German as *Münchner.*

Comment: @mach When you downvote my answer - why didn't you do it with the accepted answer above, who confirmed it? Can you verify your statement? I'm pretty sure, that "Zürcher" is alemannian and **not** standard high german!

Comment: The difference between your answer and the other answer is that you have claimed that the word is dialectal, which it is not. You can easily verify that it is standard German by consulting a Duden, where you will find that the word is not even marked as «ugs.» *(umgangssprachlich,* a kind of sub-standard).